# Work Item creation not bound to Pull Request bi-directionally

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

When creating a new Work Item of a specific type, and trying to link it to a PR at the same time, I can see that the Work Item is now shown on the Pull Request summary page.

So I'm making a fairly simple `POST` request to the `/_apis/wit/workitems/{type}` endpoint to create a new Work Item. It's working as expected for the basic properties, and since I'm adding a relation to a PR, that is also working when viewing the Work Item, but not the other way round (viewing the Pull Request shows no work item present).

My Patch Request looks like this (with the appropriate IDs in the `ArtifactLink` of course):

```
[
   {
      "from":null,
      "value":"Test Title",
      "op":"add",
      "path":"/fields/System.Title"
   },
   {
      "from":null,
      "value":"Some\\Area\\Path",
      "op":"add",
      "path":"/fields/System.AreaPath"
   },
   {
      "from":null,
      "value":"Iteration 1",
      "op":"add",
      "path":"/fields/System.IterationPath"
   },
   {
      "from":null,
      "value":"",
      "op":"add",
      "path":"/fields/System.Description"
   },
   {
      "from":null,
      "value":{
         "rel":"ArtifactLink",
         "url":"vstfs:///Git/PullRequestId/{id}%2F{id}%2F13811",
         "attributes":{
            "name":"Pull Request"
         }
      },
      "op":"add",
      "path":"/relations/-"
   }
]
```